# Android - Deciding image sizes for app

Tags: android, image

Hello there fellow programmers!

Currently I'm having problem with deciding size of an image in Android. I've read about it in [Screen Support Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) but I'm still confused about dpi and screen sizes. I have a 140x150 image in 72 dpi. If I resize it to 160 dpi (mdpi) it'll turn into a huge image. I focused on smartphones only but now I'm considering tab. Should I have made a 160 dpi image with the same size of 140 x 150, or having a huge 160dpi image is normal?

Update 7th Jan :
Found an interesting plugin in Photoshop called [Cut & Slice](http://www.cutandslice.me/), going to try it now.

Comment: You must consider the scale factor. Which is 0.75, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4 for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi, respectively. And scale the pixels accordingly. For tablets you have to create different drawable buckets, since they follow different rules than phones.

Comment: About the factor, does that mean I have to add 150x150 120dp, 150x150 160dp, and etc or that 150x150 has to be resized? Or follow the automatic rescaling when changing the dp?

Comment: The latter: to get the same dp, you must use the `scale factor` to scale the pixels.

Answer (score 0):

A pixel is just a square.
A dpi (dot per inch) corresponds to the resolution of the image.
The more pixels per inch, the sharper an image will appear because of the size of each pixel.

The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: px = dp * (dpi / 160)

You should get two images with different size for different devices to improve the quality of your pictures and, when it's for webapps, the loading speed of your pages.

To help you target some of your designs for different types of devices, here are some numbers for typical screen widths:

```
320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).
```

Comment: By size you mean the dpi?? So for example a 160 dpi image of 150x150 px can be made to 480 dpi image of 150x150 px for larger screen?

Comment: "To optimize your application's UI for the different screen sizes and densities, you can provide alternative resources for any of the generalized sizes and densities. Typically, you should provide alternative layouts for some of the different screen sizes and alternative bitmap images for different screen densities."

(Look at the edit from the post for better formatting)

Comment: How about using one layout which uses percentage of screen as the size?? I've been using it, and I'm now having problem with adjusting images, sometimes too big, sometimes blurry.

Comment: Oh so the image also resize according to the dpi itself? For example we have an image of 320x480 dpi which is mdpi in 320dp phone, but it is ldpi in a 480dp tweener tablet?